# How to split_part partial data, but partial data remain the same in SQL with MySQL,PSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I hame some data of column `name` as below:

```
 `select name from temp_test`
       name
1    ABCD-你好吗
2    CDEF-我很好
3    IDFASGASD-你好
4    你好
```

What I need is all the Chinese words, we don't need English words and '-', but not all the value is with `-` and English words, so I can't use below SQL, is there anyone knows how to achieve it?

```
SELECT split_part(b.name,'-',2) from temp_project a
left join temp_test b
on a.id=b.id and a.time = b.time;
```

Comment: MySQL or Postgres? Those are two very different database products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem by below SQL

```
SELECT CASE WHEN b.name LIKE '%-%'
     THEN SPLIT_PART(b.name, '-', 2)
     ELSE b.name END FROM temp_project a
left join temp_test b
on a.id=b.id and a.time = b.time;
```